# Default Content for Section in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewengine

I want to have some default content for a section let suppose Footer. How can I do this.

Also, what if I want to render a partial view as the default content.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Haacked blogged about this http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/05/defining-default-content-for-a-razor-layout-section.aspx.

Comment: tl;dr: No but you can haack it in if you are desperate

Answer (score 19):

```
@RenderSection("nameOfSection", required: false)
@if (!IsSectionDefined("nameOfSection"))
{
    <div>Default section content</div>
}
```